# Can i check what iOS apps a user has installed and what in app purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have already released my first iOS app and i'm working on another. I want to be able to give the new in app purchase for free to users who upgraded via an in app purchase within the first app. Is there a way to see a users in app purchase for another app? If not, can i do it so that anyone who has installed my first app, can upgrade the 2nd app for free?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Checking for Apps - Kind of.

For your own apps, you can use a [Custom URL scheme](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) to check if App1 is installed from within App2.  Some major apps (like Facebook, YouTube, etc) also have this functionality, so you can see if those apps are installed, too.

But if you're looking for an app that doesn't support this system, you're out of luck.

### Checking for In-App Purchases - No

As for checking whether a user has made an in-app purchase within another app, no, that information isn't available.

The only exception would be if you made both apps, and you store a record of the purchase on your server or designed the apps to notify each other when purchases are made.  Then, you could have App1 check the server (or the shared record) to determine if App2 has made the purchase.

### Your scenario

As for the scenario you mentioned, where a user with App1 (which you made) can upgrade within App2 (which you also made) for free, it would be kind of complicated, but certainly doable.

Basically, you'd add a custom URL scheme for each.  That would allow App2 to see if App1 is installed.  Then, within App2 you'd have some logic like this...

```
BOOL userHasInstalledAppOne = [/*here's where you check for the URL scheme*/];
if(userHasInstalledAppOne) {
    // Show "upgrade for free!" button
} else {
    // Show "purchase upgrade" button
}
```

Comment: Exactly what he said ^.

Comment: nice answer, about second question what you think if both apps supports url-schemas and call each other to share info ?

Comment: You can definitely use URLs to share info.  If you wrote both apps, you can use [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"<group identifier>"]; and share that way.  If the data is large, you can use a shared sandbox in an App Group via containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier.

Comment: Perfect answer! Seems like i'll have to release an update for app1 first with the URL scheme added before finishing and releasing app2. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know about the in-app purchases, but you can discover if the user has the other app installed, but probably you need to update this app first and add the follow property to info.plist

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>firstApp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

and then in the new app you can just check

```
var isInstalled = false
if let url = NSURL(string: "firstApp://"){
            isInstalled = UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url)
        }
```

And add this to the info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>firstApp</string>
</array>
```